# Space derivative of Brownian local time

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, schwartz-distributions

Let $\{L_x(t):(t,x)\in [0,T]\times\mathbb R\}$ be the local time of a Brownian motion $(B_t)_{t\in [0,T]}$, I know that the map $x\mapsto L_x(t)$ is $\alpha$-Hölder for $\alpha<1/2$ (uniformly in time?) continuous but by no means this implies differentiability.

Let $\xi\in S(\mathbb R)$ then using the occupation time formula we have that

\begin{align*}
        \int_0^t\xi'(B_s)ds=\int_{\mathbb R}\xi'(y)L_{y}(t)dy<\infty,\; \xi\in S(\mathbb R)
\end{align*}
and the right hand side equals $-\langle \xi, \partial_x L_x(t)\rangle$ where the angle brackets denote the dual pairing between the space $S(\mathbb R)$ and its dual.
Thus we can conclude that the local time $L_x(t)$ has a spatial derivative that is a tempered distribution.

Can we say something else regarding the regularity of this object?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you read the Wikipedia page for local times? Section 3 answers your question.

Comment: @Chaos: What kind of other regularity results are you thinking of?

Comment: Thanks! @MartinHairer Do you mean the Ray–Knight theorem? How can I use it could you mind giving me some hint?

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki Well, I was hoping that the derivative was actually a function

Comment: @Chaos: No, the local time is as irregular as the Wiener process itself.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki thanks! I've done some calculations and apparently the derivative of the Local time is actually in $S_{-p}$ for $p>17/24$ while the dirac's delta is in $S_{-p}$ for $p>5/12$, so it's even "worst" than the derivative of the wiener process

Comment: T. Yamada has examined some of the fractional derivatives of local-time-as-distribution: "On the fractional derivative of Brownian local times.  
J. Math. Kyoto Univ, vol. 25 (1985), no. 1, pp. 49–58.